# How to cut string from the closest left and right semi-colon on current cursor in codemirror?

Tags: codemirror

Iam using codemirror to write some sql query. My problem is: I will have many query, and I want to get the query that I standing at. So I will need to find the closest semi-colon on left and right, and cut them.

The function $code.getCursor(); give me "line" and "ch". But I don't care about the line and ch. A query can written in many lines, but always ended by a semi-colon. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a SQL parser that can tell you whether the given query is syntactically correct. The semi-colon logic will fail, because you can give a string with a semi-colon in it eg (select from Table where name == ":12"). You need to run the parser for many lines, till it gives you a valid query, in order to identify the multiline query.